# Figuring out what is this IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, components, multiplexer

I have this chip on a breadboard that i want to buy, in order to populate PCBs with it.

I searched and searched the internet with the text that it has on the upper part of it, but no matter how much i searched, i could not find the part.

I took some pictures, in case someone recognizes the IC.

[image]

[image]

I took two pictures, since it was hard to focus or achieve perfect lighting.
The text on top of the ICs writes "CU251 78M AN9N G4".

This is a MUX/DEMUX IC.

Comment: Digital or analog mux?

Comment: I think digital (it is connected with an arduino)

Comment: inserting your keywords in google, you get :https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/sn74cbt3251

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Thank you Marco!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entering "CU251" on https://www.ti.com/packaging/docs/partlookup.tsp gives you the [SN74CBT3251](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74CBT3251).

Comment: Nice resource. Wish more manufacturers would publish this info (I wonder if they had to do it internally to consolidate all the products from competitors they bought).